# Parsing Unescaped Json With Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-deserialization

I'm trying to parse a json response from a 3rd party API, but some of the values are unescaped.

Here's an example (taken from https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS760en-GB.json (line 35549)):

```
{
    "FHRSEstablishment": {
        "Header": {
            "ExtractDate": "2021-01-12",
            "ItemCount": "2096",
            "ReturnCode": "Success"
        },
        "EstablishmentCollection": {
            "EstablishmentDetail": [
                {
                    "FHRSID": "593073",
                    "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "EHDC5169",
                    "BusinessName": "QUALITY FRESH FISH",
                    "BusinessType": "Mobile caterer",
                    "BusinessTypeID": "7846",
                    "AddressLine2": "Stt/5/7",
                    "AddressLine3": "Fernie Brae "amanah"",
                    "AddressLine4": "Gardenstown Banff",
                    "PostCode": "AB11 8GA",
                    "RatingValue": "Pass",
                    "RatingKey": "fhis_pass_en-GB",
                    "RatingDate": "2010-03-03",
                    "LocalAuthorityCode": "760",
                    "LocalAuthorityName": "Aberdeen City",
                    "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.aberdeencity.gov.uk",
                    "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "commercial@aberdeencity.gov.uk",
                    "Scores": "",
                    "SchemeType": "FHIS",
                    "NewRatingPending": "False",
                    "Geocode": {
                        "Longitude": "-2.08854200000000",
                        "Latitude": "57.12957900000000"
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I'm using Spring Boot and `StdDeserializer`, but really struggling to find a way to parse it or at least ignore unescaped fields.

Here's an example of the `StdDeserializer` that I'm using:

```
public class FoodHygieneDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 

    public FoodHygieneDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public FoodHygieneDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public EstablishmentResponse deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        // This line throws an exception whilst trying to parse the json
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        return new EstablishmentResponse();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add to this Question one small example such of a json? That would make it self-contained. (Note.. when I paste the content of that file into an editor, I get... 1 (read: one) line.) I think it may also help if you add how you're using Spring Boot and StdDeserializer.

Comment: Parsers are written to parse valid documents but, not really to handle invalid JSON

Comment: When I open your link (in Firefox), I get `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 1053793 of the JSON data`. Data is just invalid. I guess you can run it through a Spring WebFilter before it actually reaches your controller and manipulate the data to replace ""->\" in the appropriate places, but in the end, broken is broken.

Comment: I haven't got any controllers, I'm running it as a schedued task to hit the endpoint and load the data into a database.  I would just like a way to ignore the field or fix it some how before it gets deserialized.  It may not even be possible.